# Conflict at command line between RedHat client `rhc` and a Ruby gem with the same name

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redhat, rhc

Everything was fine until I installed some Ruby gems - I was using `rhc` and the command line which was the RedHat client. After installing Ruby and some Ruby gems, I get this error when `rhc` is called:

```
 $ rhc tail foobar -p "${mypwd}"
```

stdio:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find 'rhc' (>= 0) among 30 total gem(s)
>   (Gem::LoadError)
>         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in`
>   to_spec'
>         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in
>   `gem'
>         from /usr/local/bin/rhc:22:in`'

not sure how to mitigate this - has anyone had this problem?

Comment: I think it might be because I upgraded the ruby version...

Comment: You may need to uninstall and reinstall the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Ruby expert, so this will be obvious for those that are.
But I switch Ruby versions using RVM, and so no longer had the `rhc` gem for the newer version of Ruby.